# Can I use "within" in place of "before" in "I will go there before 7 p.m."?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I will go there before 7 p.m.

Can I use "within 7 p.m." in this sentence ? Or would it be wrong to use "within"?

Comment: I will get there **by** 7.

Comment: How is this question off topic ? Can you please explain?

Comment: I've noticed that questions of this sort have an easier time staying open when the questioner includes some information showing the efforts he's made to find out the answer on his own.  But I wouldn't bother doing that with this question if I were you -- I believe the information you sought has been provided.  (If something isn't quite clear yet, you would in principle write a comment, but since you are too new a user to do that at this point, you could edit your question to add a request for further clarification.)

Comment: I will try harder next time to provide more information abou my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not correct. The following are correct:

- I will go there before 7 p.m.
- I will go there within an hour.

Answer (score -1):

No, that is not a good use of "within."

Comment: Answers on this site are expected to be definitive; please edit your post to provide an explanation of *why* you take your position, and include such references, examples, and links as may be appropriate. Otherwise, this post may be deleted as unsupported personal opinion.